# Does $C^{\infty}$ guarantee the holomorphicity?

Tags: complex-analysis

First what i learned from the textbook, is For $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, open set. 
If $f \in H(U)$ $i.e$, f is holomorphic in $U$, then $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$
which comes from the process of differentiation for cauchy integral formula.

I want to know that the inverse of above holds. $i.e$,

For $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, open set. If $f \in C^{\infty}$, then $f \in H(U)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are smooth functions $f$ that are not holomorphic (when smooth means as functions $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$). $f(z) = \bar z$ is a first counterexample. More conceptually, there are smooth functions on the complex plane that are zero on some non-empty open subset but not on all of $\Bbb C$.

That being said, "complex differentiable" usually means holomorphic. The reason for that is explained very well in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rVHLZm5Aho).